# How to match two string using java Regex

Tags: java, regex

```
String 1= abc/{ID}/plan/{ID}/planID
String 2=abc/1234/plan/456/planID
```

How can I match these two strings using Java regex so that it returns true? Basically `{ID}` can contain anything. Java regex should match `abc/{anything here}/plan/{anything here}/planID`

Comment: Try `abc/.+/plan/.+/planID`. `.+` means "any letter with the length of more than 0".

Comment: Presumably, `"String 1 =  "` and `"String 2 ="` are not actually parts of the strings, so I suggest you remove those labels. You need to make clear whether the number of forward slashes in each string is fixed at four, as in the example. If it can be variable, I don't think a regex buys you anything--just use normal Java tools. Also, I assume the strings between forward slashes (e.g., `"abc"` can be anything and not just those literals. Correct?

Comment: ...For example, do you want the same solution to also determine whether the following strings "match" in the sense you describe: `"cat/{ID}/dog/{ID}"` and `"cat/pig/dog/cow"`?

Answer (score 1):

If your "{anything here}" includes *nothing*, you can use `.*`. `.` matches any letter, and `*` means that match the string with any length with the letter before, including 0 length. So `.*` means that "match the string with any length, composed with any letter". If {anything here} should include at least one letter, you can use `+`, instead of `*`, which means almost the same, but should match at least one letter.

My suggestion: `abc/.+/plan/.+/planID`

Answer (score 1):

If {ID} can contain anything I assume it can also be empty.
So this regex should work :

```
str.matches("^abc.*plan.*planID$");
```

- ^abc at the beginning
- .* Zero or more of any Character
- planID$ at the end

Answer (score 0):

I am just writing a small code, just check it and start making changes as per you requirement. This is working, check for your other test cases, if there is any issue please comment that test case. Specifically I am using regex, because you want to match using java regex.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 

class MatchUsingRejex 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        // Create a pattern to be searched 
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("abc/.+/plan/.+/planID"); 

        // checking, Is pattern match or not
        Matcher isMatch = pattern.matcher("abc/1234/plan/456/planID"); 

        if (isMatch.find()) 
            System.out.println("Yes");
        else
            System.out.println("No");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If line always starts with 'abc' and ends with 'planid' then following way will work:

```
String s1 = "abc/{ID}/plan/{ID}/planID";
String s2 = "abc/1234/plan/456/planID";

String pattern = "(?i)abc(?:/\\S+)+planID$";

boolean b1 = s1.matches(pattern);
boolean b2 = s2.matches(pattern);
```